# R-Shiny DT: dynamic highlight

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to use a DT table in shiny, which is editable by the user.
The cells should be highlighted according to some rules (in this instance, the cells of V1 are highlighted when "new" equals 0 or 1).

However, I cannot make it work dynamically: when the user edits the values, the highlighted cells remain unchanged.
Should I use a reactive and how?

Here is my short code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),

  server = function(input, output) {

df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10)))
df$new=rownames(df)
    
    output$tbl=   renderDataTable({
      
      datatable(df, editable = T)%>% 
        formatStyle(
        'V1', 'new',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
      )
      
      })
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: My intuition would be to look at the JS `rowCallback` option, but I've couldn't make it work yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make `df` into a reactive, and access modified values via `input$tbl_cell_edit`. Second table on the right displays only second variable from your `df`.  It will display all updates to the variable V2.  See below

```
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)


    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidPage(
        column(8,DTOutput('tbl') ), column(3,DTOutput('tb2') )
      ))

    server = function(input, output) {
      DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

      observe({
        df <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10)))
        names(df) <- c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")
        df$new=rownames(df)
        rownames(df) <- NULL
        DF1$data <- df
      })  

      output$tbl <-  renderDT({
        plen <- nrow(DF1$data)
        datatable(DF1$data, class = 'cell-border stripe',
                  options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = plen, initComplete = JS(
                    "function(settings, json) {",
                    "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                    "}")),editable = TRUE) %>%
            formatStyle('V1', 'new',
            backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
            )

      })
      
      observeEvent(input$tbl_cell_edit, {
        info = input$tbl_cell_edit
        str(info)
        i = info$row
        j = info$col # + 1  # column index offset by 1
        v = info$value
        
        DF1$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, DF1$data[i, j])
      })
      
      output$tb2 <- renderDT({
        df2 <- NULL
        df2$Var1 <- DF1$data[,2]
        plen <- nrow(df2)
        df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
        datatable(df2, class = 'cell-border stripe',
                  options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = plen, initComplete = JS(
                    "function(settings, json) {",
                    "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                    "}")))
        
      })
      
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Making the df reactive doesn't help, because only the data in the `datatable` is edited, not the df itself